# Does rails3 provide any hooks for dropping in pluggable, re-usable components?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, code-reuse, modularity, ruby-on-rails-3

What efforts have been made in rails 3 to encourage code re-use? Is there anything akin to merb slices / engines built into the framework that would allow me to drop in a configurable component such as a 'blog' engine? If so, what is considered best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### On Russian dolls and mountable apps

One of the hottest new features in Rails 3 is the ability to **embed a Rails application in another Rails application**. This allows the development of components that range from user authentication to a fully featured forum.

See [here](http://yehudakatz.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/russiandolls.pdf) for more

You can also use Rack with Rails.

Comment: Looks like this didn't make the beta. http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-core/browse_thread/thread/2120fccbcbc098ad/90be0909b6a079ff